# Working with an array within an array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have an array of books. 
Books have a title and characters.
Characters have a name and age.
Both Book and Character are structs.

When my App launches a set of default Books is created (the user will also add their own later.

here is my basic code:
(NOTE: The ???? is a placeholder for the code I can't solve.)

```
struct Character {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

struct Book {
    var title: String
    var characters: [Character]
}

var books: [Book] = []

func createBooks() {
    books.append(Book(title: "My Book1", characters: ????)

}
```

I know I could probably create an array of characters and assign with

```
books.append(Book(title: "My Book1", characters: [character[0], character[3]])
```

But I'm concerned that handling the two separate arrays will become too difficult in a big list of books, not to mention user created books.

How would I best handle this?

Comment: You should choose another name for your struct Character

Comment: What's your question? Your code looks fine to me and this looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but here is how I would do this.

```
struct Character {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

struct Book {
    var title: String
    var characters: [Character]
}

var books: [Book] = []

func createBooks() {
    let character1 = Character(name: "John", age: 24)
    let character2 = Character(name: "Sarah", age: 18)
    books.append(Book(title: "My Book1", characters: [character1, character2]))
}
```

That way you a a well defined structure, you can then loop of your books like so:

```
for book in books {
    // Do something with book
}
```

and you can loop over all characters of every book like so:

```
for book in books {
    for character in book.characters {
        // Do something with character
    }
}
```

Also I very much agree with the comment from Leo Dabus, you should change the name of your Character struct to something else like BookCharacter in order to avoid confusion between char and Character in your code.